# Pass an variable to the template from the middleware in TYPO3 11.5

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I want to parse my `.browserslistrc` in the middleware of TYPO3 to decide which build should be loaded. Yes, I know that I can do it in JavaScript but I want to make the decision earlier.

This is what I return in the `process()` function:

```php
$response = $handler->handle($request->withAttribute('isModernBrowser', $isModern));
return $response;
```

`isModern` is just a boolean which contains the information if a modern or an "old" browser calls the page.

How can I catch `isModern` in my template?

Answer (score 0):

ServerRequest is available in `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_REQUEST']`. Add this object or the specific attribute with `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_REQUEST']->getAttribute('isModernBrowser')` to view.

Comment: But this is how i can catch in a PHP-Class right? i would like to use it in Fluid or TypoScript.

Comment: If you add view config to your question, I can add an example how to add required parameter to view.